# How to get Format Image from cordova/phonegap used getPicture From Gallery in Android?

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Hy guys,

i have some question about get format picture from galery used plugin phonegap/cordova. in ios, i do not have to get format, but in android i should getting format picture, example .png / .jpg / .gif.

In my code I set :

```js
navigator.camera.getPicture(uploadPhoto, function(message) {
alert('get picture failed');
}, {
quality: 50,
destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM
});
}

function uploadPhoto(imageURI) {
var options = new FileUploadOptions();
options.fileKey = "file";
if (device.platform == "Android" || device.platform == "android") {
 options.fileName = imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
}
options.mimeType = "image/jpg";
var user = Storage.getObject("user");
var params = new Object();
options.params = {
 user_id: parseInt(user.id)
}
options.chunkedMode = false;
var ft = new FileTransfer();
ft.upload(imageURI, "http://www.exampl.com/app/upload-receiptPhotoLibrary", win, fail, options);
}
```

`option.filename` not result file with format file, how to get format file in `option.filename` ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the mime type

```
var sFile = new MediaFile("some.jpg", "file:///mnt/sdcard/some.jpg");
console.log("file path = " + sFile.fullPath);
sFile.getFormatData(function(metadata) {
    console.log("mimeType = " + metadata.type);
}, function() {
    console.log("fail");
});
```

Comment: Hy murtaza , what is empty.txt ?

for now,  example return from option.filename = content://media/external/images/media/17, how to get complete filename+format ?